# Pass different data types into function that returns nothing

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have a class method that returns nothing but modifies an instance variable of the current object, it needs to be able to take in two different data types as the same parameter (An instance of the class or a number).

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod([EITHER MyClass x OR double x])
    {
        if(x is MyClass)
        {
            //do something
        } 
        else
        {
            //do something else
        }
    }
```

Comment: The solution of @IpsitGaur would then check the type at runtime. Alternative: create two methods with the same name.

Comment: Create two *overloaded* versions of the function (using the same function name), one that takes a `MyClass` instance and one that takes a `double`.

Comment: In 99.5% of cases, you should implement this as two separate methods, as per @Flydog57's suggestion.

Comment: You can't pass an instance variable of `double` to a method and then expect to modify it in such a way that it reflects on the instance variable.  `double` is passed by **value**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overload the method MyMethod like below.

```
public void MyMethod(MyClass x) {  

}  
public void MyMethod(double x) {  

}
```

Comment: OP _"but modifies an `instance variable` of the `current object`"_ - how is thing going to work for `double` which is passed **by value**?

Answer (score 1):

Use [method overloading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-method-overloading/) as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod(MyClass x)
    {
        // do anything with MyClass 
    }

    public void MyMethod(double x)
    {
       // do anything with double
    }
}
```

Comment: in this example using 'MyMethod' method in 2 different forms. 1 . for MyClass, 2. for double

Answer (score -1):

Please check if below may be helpful.

```
     public static void MyTestObjectClass(object value)
        {
            Type getTypeOfParam = value.GetType();//Get type of parameters. 
            //Handle on  getTypeOfParam, you will get namespace.yourType
            if(getTypeOfParam==?)
            {
                //Then do here
            }

        }
```

Comment: urm... `MyGenericClass` really? besides all that, this is a very messy solution to a simple problem

Comment: I changed class name. The requirement is like same i tried to give solution